What are the ideal settings for printing a lampshade?
I have a Creality Ender 3 printer with a bed size of 235 x 235 mm and a nozzle width of 0.8 mm. I need to print a lampshade using PLA filament of 1.75 mm that I made in Blender of the following dimensions:

height : 203 mm
diameter : 227 mm
thickness : 1 mm
base thickness : 3 mm



I am using Ultimaker Cura to slice the model.
What are the ideal print settings do I use to print it such that:

It prints as one object.

There are no seams.

The object prints upwards in a spiral pattern [left]:

Currently it prints to a point and retraces back to the start point, thus creating the seam.

In one of my test prints the object had artifacts and errors on the inner surface as follows (how do I avoid this?):


The object should be hard enough that it doesn't flex too much.


I am new at 3D printing and don't know the terms and it would be great if you could explain in a bit of detail.
Please note I cannot use supports for this.

The answer given to me was thought to be correct but on implementation didn't solve all the issues and what didn't it solve then? Please explain. I think this may be quite essential if you want to attract new answers. An answer to develop your own slicer may be too far from your objective.

Consider using vase mode or “Spiralize Outer Contour.” It will print continuously upwards with no travel moves but it will only have a thickness of ~0.9mm.
Tom's Hardware:
This feature allows you to produce 3D prints with a continuous, spiral, single outer wall with a smooth surface finish. It does this by slowly increasing the Z-axis continuously. It can also speed up print times while using less material.

This, spiral vase mode.

The OP has a 0.8 mm nozzle, that would easily extrude the requested 1.0 mm thickness of the vase. I'd push it to 1.2 to 1.4 mm for more rigidity.

is this in ultimaker cura as well? where do i find it? Also what do i set the other settings to then?

addendum : the link finally opened... i see what you mean.

@0scar as in increase the nozzle size? no can do, this is a target spec for a client... i'm testing it out and finalizing a workflow, but i cant swap nozzles

@Tejas: You don't have to increase nozzle size to increase extrusion width. Just set the line width to 1.0 or 1.2 or whatever you want. The only reason to ever increase nozzle size is if you want to print thick layers, since layers thicker than about 70-75% of the nozzle orifice width don't print well. Otherwise, sticking with a smaller nozzle size and just requesting a wider line width works just as well or better than increasing nozzle size.

@R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE and what do i set the layer height to?

@Tejas: I would use whatever your normal layer height is. With 0.8 mm nozzle, I would expect that to be somewhere in the range of 0.2 to 0.5 mm. Thinner layers will give a smoother appearance. Thicker ones will give a characteristic 3D printed layer look, which some people like for this type of print. With wide lines and thick layers, you'll have to go really slow not just to ensure you can keep up melting the plastc, but in order to be able to cool it before you get around to it on the next layer, so it doesn't sag.
